# Xcode not autocompleting Parse functions in Swift

Tags: xcode, autocomplete, parse-platform, swift

I'm trying to build an app written in Swift that uses Parse, but I've realized that my Xcode no longer provides autocomplete for any of the Parse functions. The app still compiles and builds with no problem on the iOS simulator so I know the framework is being read/compiled correctly but it's very frustrating to develop without being able to use the autocomplete features, especially since the API Reference doesn't yet have Swift code.

For my current project, I added pod Parse to my Podfile and thus added the sdk that way. I've also followed the instructions here: http://blog.parse.com/2014/06/06/building-apps-with-parse-and-swift/ to create a `Appname-Bridging-Header.h` file, adding `#import <Parse/Parse.h>` there to import the header file. So I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Probably a compiler bug. There's certainly no shortage of them.

Comment: At this point, anything I can do besides just waiting it out?

Comment: Unlikely. Keep the parse docs open.

Comment: The API reference does have Swift code, try refreshing then toggle between Objective-C and Swift for each sample block.

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely some support for autocompleting bridged Obj-C libraries into swift but it's not perfect yet.

For example, if you subclass PFQueryTableViewController and type 'tableview' on a new line, all the standard UITableViewController protocol methods appear as autocomplete, in addition to the PFQueryTableViewController-specific method:

`override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell!`

However, this isn't really a Parse-specific issue and will probably improve with new releases of swift/Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood question correctly, try this:

var gameScore **: PFObject** = PFObject(className: "GameScore")

or

var gameScore = PFObject(className: "GameScore") **as PFObject**

I had issue with swift's methods' autocompletion after the object was created, because XCode couldn't recognize class of new object if you don't write it manually.

Comment: I don't believe you understand the question correctly, and both of those downcasts are unnecessary.

Comment: Nick, I don't know about Parse objects, but my own objects needs this unnecessary downcasts. To reproduce it: Create new swift file, write there simple class with 2 vars, init method to define this vars and 1 function. Then, open any of your viewcontrollers and in viewdidload method try to create object like this:  **let message = MessageManger(subj:"test",message:"test")**. Then try to accesss object fuction with autocomplete by writing "**message.**" It will be no autocomplete. But if I write **let message : MessageManager**, it will work. May be I have any mistake in my class, I don't know.